# Jquery: add html to text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery that I am using to insert some text based on an IF statement, this works perfectly but I need to now add a new class to this text to style it, but when I do this it does not render anything.

Existing and working script.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        if($('.productdetail').length){
        }else{
       document.getElementById('listwrapper').innerHTML = "Sorry! Your search found no products, please adjust your filters. If you need help call (02) 9620 2424."
         } 
      });
```

What I did and broke it:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        if($('.productdetail').length){
        }else{
       document.getElementById('listwrapper').innerHTML = "<span class='sorry'>Sorry! Your search found no products, please adjust your filters. If you need help call (02) 9620 2424.</span>"
         } 
      });
```

Any advice or help would be awesome!

Comment: `$('#listwrapper').html("<span class='sorry'>Sorry! Your search found no products, please adjust your filters. If you need help call (02) 9620 2424.</span>")`?

Comment: Your code works [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/MJ8Dc/). You should check if your `.sorry` class `display/visibility` is not set to `none`

Comment: what is `listwrapper` ?

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/z8sKf/

Comment: Works fine here. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/989w2/1/)** check your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.html()` in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($('.productdetail').length){
        }
        else{
              $('#listwrapper').html("<span class='sorry'>Sorry! Your search found no products, please adjust your filters. If you need help call (02) 9620 2424.</span>");
         } 
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

Use like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.productdetail').length){
    }else{
   document.getElementById('listwrapper').html("<span class='sorry'>Sorry! Your search found no products, please adjust your filters. If you need help call (02) 9620 2424.</span>");}
  });
```